# how to solve the jruby issue of asciidoctor in the docker container

Tags: java, maven, docker, asciidoctor

I have a issue with asciidoctor. My application is working when I am running it outside the docker container. When I am using maven build to generate the jar and run it inside the docker container, it shows :

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- 
asciidoctor
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:961)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META- 
INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)
    at RUBY.<main>(<script>:12)

asciidoctorj: 1.5.6
asciidoctor-pdf: 1.5.0-alpha.15
org.jruby:jruby-complete: 1.7.26
dockerfile: openjdk:8u111-jdk
intellij
```

please help if anyone knows the way to solve the issue, thx!

Comment: How are you creating the jar? It sounds like it's missing a dependency. Either create a fat jar or add the dependency to the Java runtime classpath in the Docker container.

Comment: I am using maven build: clean compile package to generate the jar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: I try to build a fat jar with the last post:<dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
  </dependency>. I run it in the docker container again, it first shows java out of memory issue, so I change the java_options from Xmx256 to Xmx1024, then it shows: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException , Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine code source archive from file